# Create a slightly overlapping bar chart with plotly

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I have the `plotly` bar chart below which displays sent and clicked emails. As clicked emails are included into sent I would like to display them as slightly overlapping instead of a grouped bar chart.
something like:

[image]

```
Emails <- c("g", "o", "m")
Sent <- c(20, 24, 33)
Clicked <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Emails, Sent, Clicked)
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Emails, y = ~Sent, type = 'bar', name = 'Sent',marker=list(color="#556361"),
               hoverinfo = paste(Emails,Sent))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Clicked, name = 'Clicked',marker=list(color="#A72608"),
                         hoverinfo = paste(Emails,Clicked))

fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')

fig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually I don't how to create that desired plot output via plotly syntax. I generally use ggplot syntax then turn it into a plotly output thanks to `plotly::ggplotly()`

Here is my ggplot based code and (relatively) plotly solution;

```
Emails <- c("g", "o", "m")
Sent <- c(20, 24, 33)
Clicked <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Emails, Sent, Clicked)


data %>%
melt(value.name = 'n',id.vars = 'Emails',variable.name = 'type')  %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Emails,y=n,fill=type))+
geom_col(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.5,jitter.height = 0,jitter.width = 0,seed = 25)) -> gg_output


plotly_object <- plotly::ggplotly(gg_output)

plotly_object
```

[image]